# Multiple instances of a script populating a mySQL database ->

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database and I have three tables:

```
     settings
Name     |   Value
curId    |    127 
contentId|    34


content1
Id   |   Name
5    |   XXX
34   |   YYY

content2
Id   |   Name
12   |   XXX
33   |   YYY
```

The script I have is taking data from another "DB" using the curId from the settings table and then if it exists in the other "DB" adds it to the content1 table if it doesn't tthen it adds it the content2 table. Both of them share the same id and we get it from settings[çontentid]. After each try it will increment the contentId and curId, so that I know where it failed/stopped/finished last. Now I want to run two instances of the script. Both of them taking the id from settings[curId] and incrementing it after done.

My question is: If I just let them run without using any locks will it happen that at some point the get same object from the other "DB" and make a duplicate in content1.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will happen, but it could possibly happen.
Why don't you let them start from different values to a certain limit? that way you wouldn't even need the first table.

Comment: I just added the third table that I forgot about and I have though about this and the contentId is the same problem as with curId.

Comment: Yeah, you would have the same problem. the cleanest was would be to synchronize your access on the db.

Comment: So every time I access the settings table I should lock and unlock after that. I'm thinking of RW lock or will Read lock just do it?

Comment: In what language is the script you have?

Comment: PHP but I don't think it matters at all the language.